# Factory Girl: NameError: uninitialized constant Vserver

Tags: ruby, rspec, tdd, sinatra, factory-bot

I am trying to setup the unit testing with Factory Girl and Rspec for my Sinatra application.

Gem file:

```
group :test do
  gem "rack-test"
  gem "fuubar"
  gem "factory_girl"
  gem "yard"
end
```

## spec/factories/vserver.rb

```
require 'factory_girl'

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :vserver do
    first_name "John"
    last_name  "Doe"
  end
end
```

## spec/spec_helper.rb

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "..", "app.rb")

%w{
  rubygems
  sinatra
  dm-core
  rack/test
  uuid
  factory_girl
  rspec
  pp

  spec/factories/vserver
}.each { |r| require r }

set :environment, :test

# RSpec without Rails
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end
```

## spec/app_spec.rb

```
require './spec_helper.rb'
require 'factory_girl'

describe "Cdot" do

include Rack::Test::Methods

def app
  StorageApi
end

it 'vserver' do

  FactoryGirl.build(:vserver)

end

end
```

Issue: When I run the rspec file using the command: rspec app_spec.rb, I get the below error.

NameError: uninitialized constant Vserver

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code: `factory :vserver do` assumes that you have a class called `Vserver` that you are instantiating.

If you have such a class, then you need to include it in your spec.

If you don't have such a class, then you either need to rename the factory, or tell it what class it should be instantiating instead.

Comment: I have provided the reference of the class in the spec_helper.rb and it still shows the same issue.

Comment: can you edit your question to show the updated code? Also - the relevant class?

Comment: Hi Sorry after carefully looking at the references, i found that I have not referenced the class I am instantiating. Thank you very much for your help. It solved my issue.